# Scaling layer contents when animating layer-backed view

Tags: cocoa, animation, core-animation, autolayout, appkit

I'm animating a layer-backed view that contains several subviews. Everything is laid out using auto layout. Currently, as I animate the view, the subviews are not being scaled along with it:

[image: animation]

I'd like the whole thing to be drawn once, at their final size, then scaled as it animates. The `layerContentsPlacement` and `layerContentsRedrawPolicy` properties seem to be what I'm looking for, but changing them don't seem to have any effect.

Here's a basic run-through of how I'm doing the animation:

```
// Add itemView to canvas
NSView *itemView = // ...
itemView.layerContentsPlacement = NSViewLayerContentsPlacementScaleProportionallyToFit;
itemView.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawBeforeViewResize;
[parentView addSubview:itemView];

// Add constraints for the final itemView frame ...

// Layout at final state
[parentView layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];

// Set initial animation state
itemView.alphaValue = 0.0f;
itemView.frame = // centered zero'ed frame

// Set final animation state
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
  context.duration = 0.25f;
  context.allowsImplicitAnimation = YES;

  itemView.alphaValue = 1.0f;
  [parentView layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
} completionHandler:nil];
```

Comment: Short answer: don't resize the view as the animation. Scale it with a transform instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to David's comment I switched to using a transform on the view's layer.

The basic idea is to create and layout your view as you normally would, then create and add some CA animations to the view's layer.

```
// Add item view to canvas
NSView *itemView = // ...
[parentView addSubview:itemView];

// Add constraints for the final item view positioning

// Layout at final state
[parentView layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];

// Animate
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];
animation.duration = 1.0f;
[itemView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform"];

// create any other animations...
```